# Guilty Crown stream by Funimation?

Tags: guilty-crown

Guilty Crown appears to be available for free (streaming) on Funimation's website: http://www.funimation.com/shows/guilty-crown

There is a column labeled "Watch Free", but when I click it for any episode it takes me to a page with a video asking me to buy and become a "Elite Video Subscriber".

What am I missing?

Comment: That's funny, their "Elite" and "Watch Free" link go to the same place. Though not terribly obvious, I believe they mean that you can watch it with the "free trial," which (strangely enough) requires a purchase. Clearly they need to rethink their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, with Funimation, subbed episodes can be streamed for free; some other shows will also have the first couple dubbed episodes free for streaming, but this isn't the case with Guilty Crown.

It seems that the links on the main page of a number of shows aren't quite placed right - the "elite" and "watch free" links go to the same page. You can watch any subbed episodes without being a subscriber by going to the "Videos" tab on the main page and then mousing over the thumbnail for the episode and selecting "watch sub".